# Ubuntu 22.04 - Raspberry Pi - IMX219 Camera - How to use camera stack?

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, camera

I need to use Ubuntu 22.04 (due to ROS) and would like to use the IMX219 camera with it.
First of all, everything worls just fine with the newest Raspbian.

When I try this minimal example, the image content is empty.

```py
import cv2

# open camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L)

# set dimensions
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 2560)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1440)

# take frame
ret, frame = cap.read()
# write frame to file
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', frame)
# release camera
cap.release()
```

It seems like the camera is not working correctly with Ubuntu 22-04.

What camera stack is used? How do I use it?
Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the package is a snap, in what way is it not compatible? also, to be clear, the "enabling the camera" step is done before installing any packages; the package is just a "demo" of the camera's abilities. You can look at the source code of the package to see how it's done.

Comment: The package is not available for arm64.

Comment: the tutorial seems to use it on a raspberry pi... which is always arm based

Comment: I added another minimal example using opencv. And it comes down to the same issue, the image seems to be not available.